# How to update kernel after ubuntu server 10 -> 12 update

Tags: server, grub2, kernel

I have a remote VPS which had ubuntu server 10.04 installed (for some reason the hosting company doesn't have 12.04 yet)

I recently downgraded my hardware to a VPS from a dedicated machine and transferred the list of installed packages to the new VPS after I updated it to 12.04.

The problem is the VPS is still running and old kernel, I've tried updating it but it doesn't seem to want to run a newer kernel, I thought it may be a problem with grub so I ran update-grub:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-39-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-34-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-49-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-59-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-58-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-56-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: no such disk.
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Cannot find list of partitions!  (Try mounting /sys.)
```

However as you can see I'm getting a heap of errors.

I'm not to sure what's going on.

Comment: What virtualization software is the host running? Can you post the output of `mount`? It is possible that the virtualization software does not allow you to replace the kernel. This will be the case if they are using [OS level virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization) like Xen or LXC. What is the out of `uname -a`?

Comment: I didn't consider that but yeh, here's the output: Linux euve37573 2.6.32-042stab084.21 #1 SMP Thu Jan 30 17:33:42 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
       /dev/vzfs on / type reiserfs (rw,usrquota,grpquota)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VPS host is running [Parallels Virtuozzo Containers](http://www.parallels.com/products/pvc/) (hence the ZVFS filesystem on root). This is an [Operating System Virtualization](http://www.parallels.com/products/pvc/os-virtualization/) product - a single kernel is shared between all of the virtual hosts and you can not change it or update it.

Comment: That really sucks, I've ordered a new dedicated server so everything should be fixed now.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with OS virtualization, as long as you do not require a custom kernel.

Comment: Yeah true but I've found their VPS to be horribly unstable. Thanks for the help though :)